# Powershell copy-item : the file name is being changed

Tags: powershell

I will really appreciate your kind support as this is related to patients care and privacy.

I'm writing the below script for a hospital where the patient medical images/videos should be copied to another folder for archiving purposes.

The workflow is: the device stores an `AVI` & `THB` file in the folder with the exact same name, the syntax for the file name is `ID_DATE` eg:

- 123456_2112019.AVI
- 123456_2112019.THB

My script is watching this folder and copy the AVI file only to another folder.

The problem is that the `AVI` file is being copied successfully but the name is trimmed, it removes everything before the underscore, so the file `123456_2112019.AVI` becomes `_2112019.AVI`

I noticed that the `THB` file is the root cause for this problem as I tested on a different folder without the presence of the `THB` file and the copy operation worked successfully without changing the name.

Could you please advise how to fix this? here is my code

```
$folder = 'D:\test'
$filter = '*.AVI'                             

$fsw = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $true              
    NotifyFilter          = [System.IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {

    [int]$sleepTime = 500
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
    Write-Host $path -fore Green
    Write-Host $name -fore Green
    Write-Host $changeType -fore Green
    Write-Host $timeStamp -fore Green

    try {
        # **********check if the file is locked by another process (still being received from the soource)********
        function Test-FileLock {
            param (
                [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$Path
            )

            $oFile = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $Path

            if ((Test-Path -Path $Path) -eq $false) {
                return $false
            }

            try {
                $oStream = $oFile.Open([System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::ReadWrite, [System.IO.FileShare]::None)

                if ($oStream) {
                    $oStream.Close()
                }
                $false
            }
            catch {
                # file is locked by another process.

                return $true
            }
        }
        #******** End of Function (test if file is locked) *****************
        # below line : will keep testing if the file is locked ************
        while (Test-FileLock $path) { Start-Sleep 10 }

        # below line: once the file becomes "NOT Locked" , copy the file to the destination folder *******
        Copy-Item  $path  'D:\output' -Force -Verbose -PassThru 
    }
    catch {
        $error|Out-File  -FilePath d:\outlog.txt -Append
        $Error.Clear()
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the same script and it worked perfectly for me. It didn't trim AVI file. I used .THB as well along with creating .AVI file.
Can you test it on different folder along with THB file as well? I don't think *.THB file is causing issue here.

Comment: @MuditBahedia, so your script is copying both AVI and THB files, do the file names contain _underscore_ ? can you share your code. I still have the problem.

Comment: Yes, I used the same file names from your question `123456_2112019.AVI` and it had `_` in it. I didn't modify any code. It's copying *.AVI only.

Comment: Yes I guess this will work if the files already exist in the folder, but in my case the script is watching the folder and the machine is producing the files and putting them in the folder and the THB file is always reaches the folder first due to its small size, I know this shouldn't make problem , but the problem is persist

Comment: I can hardly believe that `.thb`has any influence to a target name for `.avi` since it's not related in any way with the copying process.

Comment: I totally agree, but I have the problem on 9 computers as there are 9 medical devices. Any suggestion that may come to your mind? is it the _underscore_ then?

Comment: Are you sure there's no process renaming the files *after* you've copied them? You can use procmon from sysinternals to verify what file actually gets created in the first place.

Comment: Personally, I have never seen anyone define a function inside a `try{..} catch{..}` block before. Feels strange to me. Is there any difference in behavior if you move that up and out of the try-catch block?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers @Theo , even before the `try` statement, when the `Write-Host $name -fore Green` is executed , it writes the file name trimmed, means the file name is being trimmed before any function and before even the `Copy` operation.